# Setup of swagger-ui-express with API Gateway

Tags: express, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway, swagger-ui

I am not able to figure out the correct setup of either my API Gateway or swagger-ui-express.
The lambda function runs successful and and return the html but the related resouces are not able to be loaded and get an 404 error.

```
const app = express();
const swaggerUI = require('swagger-ui-express');
const serverlessExpress = require('@vendia/serverless-express');

const Stage = process.env.Stage;
const apiId = process.env.apiId;
const options = {
    customCss: '.swagger-ui .topbar { display: none }',
    customCss: '.swagger-ui .topbar { background-color: red }'
}

let serverlessExpressInstance

async function asyncTask() {
    // load latest spec from API Gateway export removed to simplicity reasons.
    const swaggerDocument = spec;
    console.log("load swagger file complete.");
    return swaggerDocument
}

async function setup(event, context) {
    const swaggerDocument = await asyncTask()
    console.log(swaggerDocument)

    app.use('/api-doc', swaggerUI.serveWithOptions({ redirect: false }));
    app.use('/api-doc', swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocument, options));
    console.log("setup of swagger complete");

    serverlessExpressInstance = serverlessExpress({ app })
    return serverlessExpressInstance(event, context)
}

function handler(event, context) {
    if (serverlessExpressInstance) return serverlessExpressInstance(event, context)
    return setup(event, context)
}

exports.handler = handler
```

Setup on API Gateway is the following:

[image: API Gateway resources]

Both resources are pointing to the lambda function.
When I load the page via: https://.execute-api..amazonaws.com/dev/api-doc
The following errors are raised:

[image: Error logs]

How can I ensure that the resources are loaded correctly via the correct path ...dev/api/doc/...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probbably getting these errors because swagger-ui is configured to look for the image/js resources and express doesn't serve these files. You could potentially use something like `serverless-http` like [this](https://www.qloudx.com/building-a-swagger-ui-for-your-api-in-aws-api-gateway/), but I'm not really sure it's a good idea to try and force express into the response of an API gateway lambda function.

As an alternative I managed to get swagger up and running on an API Gateway lambda function, fetching the swagger JSON directly.

```
import { APIGateway } from "aws-sdk";
import { env } from "../../helpers/env";

const API_ID = env("API_ID", "");

export const handler = async () => {
  const apiGateway = new APIGateway({
    apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
  });
  const apiGatewayExport = await apiGateway
    .getExport({
      exportType: "swagger",
      restApiId: API_ID,
      stageName: "prod",
      accepts: "application/json",
      parameters: {
        extensions: "apigateway",
      },
    })
    .promise();

  if (!apiGatewayExport.body) {
    throw new Error("No body found in API Gateway Export");
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/html",
    },
    body: generateSwaggerPageBody(apiGatewayExport.body?.toString()),
  };
};

const generateSwaggerPageBody = (swaggerSpec: string) => `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Swagger</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="swagger"></div>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
            <script>
              SwaggerUIBundle({
                dom_id: '#swagger',
                spec: ${swaggerSpec}
            });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>`;
```

I'm taking the API information directly from API Gateway via SDK and then I just return an html page with  tags loading swagger directly - no express overhead needed.

Comment: the serverless-http link you provided was very helpful to me. Thank you